# Reasons against using "Git" in the enterprise

Tags: git

I was recently using a commercial centrally controlled version control system in a large company with about 100 different subsystems written in different operating systems and languages, and I have noticed that several developers use either git or mercurial on their pet projects, but not for their work systems. I personally am more familiar with git but was wondering what reasons are their to "Not" use Git in the enterprise, apart from the fact that the choice has already been made (we have many problems with our centrally controlled version system, so I can't say it is brilliant).

## Update

The world has indeed changed since I wrote this. The company in question that actually disallowed Git at the time now uses Mercurial as their preferred system

Comment: "several developers use either git or mercurial on their pet projects, but not for their work systems" - you should ask them.  You certainly shouldn't be making assumptions about my enterprise software development.

Comment: @dustin. Yes, you are right, I did ask the developers, in fact the first thing I did was ask them why they don't use Git for work. The answer was always, "Because they use XXX technology here" and noone wants to rock the boat. If you are using git or mercurial in a large company where git or mercurial is the official version control system then it is the first I have heard of. Congratulations! :)

Comment: The company I work for uses git. Because I set it up.

Comment: @mikhail - How many people in your company? Or rather, how many people in the IT department?

Comment: @Zubair You caught me, its not large. About 5 people in the IT department.

Comment: @mikhail - 5 people, still good :) Well I think that things are starting to change in companies, even in larger ones they are starting to use Mercurial and Git these days. Good luck with your company, I guess Git is only going to grow in usage :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have to disagree with the ideas that Enterprises are afraid of free or that they are slow to change.  These may be true but to use them to dismiss the slow adoption rate of git in the Enterprise space misses the point of what Enterprise means.  Besides, SVN is pretty popular and it's free.

Enterprise is about centralization.  You want all your developers to follow the same procedure, get the same code, etc.

Eric Sink is more eloquent on this subject than I could be: http://www.ericsink.com/articles/vcs_trends.html

Comment: It's not so much that they're afraid of free, per se, but they know what free means: no support.

Comment: Again, svn is in the same boat, support-wise.

Comment: @dclowd9901 Support is independent of whether a thing is Free or not. And support isn't just what you pay for, the quality of git support and turn around time is probably faster than any commercial support. But you likely mean paid support. Subversion has paid support via collab.net. Support for git can be gotten through clearvision-cm.com and github. Are they any good? No idea! But "Enterprise support" is more about being a security blanket than quality.

Comment: @Schwern - No, (as with all free tools) support is (at those places) if someone knows approximately how to fix the problem. And has the interest to work on it. If not; you're out of luck. And that just doesn't work in industry. With paid support (regulated) if they don't know how to fix it, they're getting a work order to find a way - whether they feel like it. In regulated time. They're also responsible. Mercurial is somewhat better in this respect, though.

Comment: @Rook No... to what?  Which are "those places"?  If you're paying somebody for support, you expect support.  That's orthogonal to if it's a free tool or a paid one.  I feel like we just had a violent agreement.

Comment: @Schwern - No to that quality of support is independent to being free or not. I don't think that free support is bad (in this case is excellent), but have always considered it somewhat unreliable. It depends on whether someone at (those places=where you get free support) *is feeling like helping* (bad wording, but you'll get the meaning I gather), unlike commercial support which is a contractual agreement (in one form or another). That is why industry prefers paid support. /// Oh, and I didn't mean to argue. Sorry if it came out that way. ///

Comment: Btw, I don't see that github offers commercial support as a company.

Comment: @Rook We are having a violent agreement. I'm talking about *paid* support for a *free* product.  As in paying a company to support git or SVN.  You can get paid support for your Git if your company really wants it, so it's a red herring as to why you shouldn't use  like Git in the "Enterprise". That paid support might be crap, but that's true for any paid support of any product. And business might not realize you can get paid support for git.  (I think I assumed paid support is rolled into the paid plans on Github)

Comment: @Schwern - No, we're just discussing. What do you find violent in here? I'm too talking about paid support for a free product. However, to the best of my knowledge, github does not offer it. Some individuals offer training and such, but in their private/semi employed capacity. I cannot (again, to the best of my knowledge - their page is somewhat vague on that matter) ask github to provide constant support for my business,  for example, for the next two years?

Comment: As far as "That paid support might be crap, but that's true for any paid support of any product." that depends on the extend of your interest on it. You would be suprised! (when dealing with individuals probably; when dealing with a larger office very much opposite)

Answer (score 12):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's because enterprise has always been wary about using "free" things. Mostly because they lack a stable support system (generally, support comes in the form of StackOverflow.com or forums when it comes to open-source), but there's also a pervasive mentality of "you get what you pay for." They figure if it doesn't cost them a buttload in licensing fees, it must be worth as much in terms of real usability.

Of course, we, as tech experts, know that's a load.

Comment: support is a huge factor.  I was going to suggest it was because git is rather complicated and has a higher learning curve than other solutions, but yea, I think support trumps it.

Comment: Yeah, but at the same time, how often do you lodge a support ticket against your VCS... We used VSS for a long time, and while it was pants, we never raised a ticket for it.

Comment: Paddy: It's not just "how often do you need it", but the product of that and "what's the cost of not having it".  I've never filed a support ticket against my VCS, but I have filed a support ticket against my database, and without that, I would have been totally sunk.  I'll take "1,000:1 you find a bug that kills your business, plus support" over "1,000,000:1 with no support" any day.

Comment: @Ken: Of course, with the git mailing list out there, and a maintainer like Junio Hamano, and Linus still around, you can hardly say git has no support. You'll get fast response to a severe bug.

Comment: Caninical offers or is to offer support for Bazaar.  FogCreek offers support for Mercurial-based Kiln.  GitHub offers support for Git-based GitHub:FI.

Comment: @Joel - I just asked this question the other day. Several companies offer commercial support for Merc. / (not Kiln)

Answer (score 8):

### In my experience, **Enterprises have a lot of anti-bodies against change**

1. **Existing skill-sets**: if large part of the team has skills on existing tools, they will automatically become an obstacle of changing them, even for better ones.
2. **Consolidated stability**: change is always a pain in terms of migration and stability. What is in production "works by nature" and every change always create problems.
3. **Compliance**: existing tools have been analysed and validated by Enterprise ICT Security and then defined as "standard and compliant" with company procedures. Anything different will be seen as a potential security risk.

IMHO then the problem **is not** GIT itself or a Distributed Version Control: the problem is changing the SCM and going toward something unknown and potentially "dangerous" for the Enterprise ruleset. That's why the "antibodies" comes into play to prevent any significant change.

More specifically on GIT, many risks and threats are providing additional arguments against its adoption, related to the three points mentioned above:

1. Skills-set: GIT is different from any other SCM used so far. Naming is ambiguous and misleading (the "svn checkout" is a "git clone" ... whilst a "git commit" *is not* a "svn commit")
2. Consolidated stability: GIT has been very unstable till Ver. 1.6. We have used it on Windows since Ver. 1.5 and it has been a real pain, particularly with unexperienced devs.
3. Compliance: GIT has no identity enforcement by default and doesn't provide a clear trace of who did what. It is "peer-to-peer" so by nature is against central control and auditing.

I have seen the "anti-bodies" in action many times before GIT:

- 1996: migration from RCS to CVS
- 2001: migration from SourceSafe to CVS
- 2005: migration from CVS to Subversion
- 2009: migration from Subversion to Git

In **all those examples** has been key to highlight the plus and minus of the change in an Enterprise-wide terms: evaluating risks, costs and benefits ... and all with clearly in mind who are the anti-bodies and how can we mitigate them or "assure a nice alley for them to walk with old tools".

After a lot of pain and effort, **all those migrations were eventually very successful !** I have introduced GIT in large enterprises such as *Vodafone Group Services in the UK and Germany*. After pain and resistance anyway, the change has taken off and benefits are visible and have already **provided a significant ROI in terms of efficiency, agility and control**.

On the compliance and support side, I have seen helping positively the adoption of Vendor-assisted sponsorship. Some examples:

- CollabNet (http://www.collab.net) for SubVersion adoption with RBAC
  Security
- GitEnterprise (http://www.gitenterprise.com) for Git Enterprise
  compliance with SOX and CMMI
- Google (http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) for Gerrit Code Review
  introduction and change tracking

---

Generally speaking, change is the **most expensive but MORE IMPORTANT task in a large Enterprise**, first of all from the point of view of people mindset.

Let me know what you think about Git and Enterprise Tools adoptions !

*Luca / @lucamilanesio*

Answer (score 7):

Some of the many reasons:

- Inertia: There's an enormous number of people out there familiar with centralized systems. You don't have to "retrain" developers if you just don't change.
- Interactions with other tools: Corporate environments are of course big on extra tools like continuous integration, IDEs, fancy issue trackers, and so on. Naturally, there's more support for the established centralized VCSs with those than with the relatively new git and hg.
- Support: When you buy a commercial VCS product, you're not just buying the program, you're buying peace of mind.

Of course, I'm not saying these are *good* reasons; they're just convincing to people in the position to make this decision. I think it's worth overcoming inertia - it takes work now, but it pays off later. I think the external tools are getting better at supporting git, particularly the open-source ones - they just need plugins. And as for support, we all know there's plenty of less formal support out there on the internet.

Really, there's a common thought in all of these - the free software philosophy just isn't the way corporations do business. Buying a product is established and easy. You pay your money, you get what you need. Management doesn't have to worry. Using a free software product... well, it may be much better, but it's more complex to deal with. It doesn't come in a box.

A clarification: I use the word "free" in the same way those in the free software world do - free as in freedom not as in beer. Hopefully this phrase will get drilled into everyone's heads eventually. Note that I never dealt with the issue of cost here - though I do think that in the case of git, in general it will be ultimately be cheaper than a purchased solution despite the costs of bringing everyone up to speed on it and making sure it fits in with the rest of your process. This isn't a cut-and-dry issue though, and since I think git comes out ahead, there's no sense putting it among the bullets.

Comment: Free software isn't always *free* in the enterprise world (with emphasis on your first two bullet points -- those cost money in the enterprise world).  Even the cost of support can be offset with possibly having to hire another employee dedicated to the tasks the support contract would have provided.  Though I do agree with you that they aren't *good* reasons for using an inferior tool.

Comment: Although the professional costs of psychiatric care for devs forced to use VSS and the security guards for when they go postal are also rather high.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience it is the fear of change. Source code management is a central piece of infrastructure and affects all developers. If the current system doen't hurt too much enterprise IT will actually fight change.

Another reason I've heard quite often is that IDE integration has not yet reached the quality of e.g. CVS or Subversion. Though the argument is true it is becoming increasingly lees an issue.

Comment: Xcode 5 has decent git integration. In my opinion, better submodule support than Xcode 4 had, too.

Answer (score 4):

This same question can be asked about switching any large infrastructure service with something else. When there are hundreds or thousands of people using something, it had better be broken or the new thing had better offer some compelling features.

Think about switching email systems. Someone is going to have to train all the users, transfer all of the messages, make the switch with minimal downtime and without losing data, and then convince management it isn't going to cause a major disruption to business operations.

In your specific example, converting the source control system for 100 subsystems while retaining history and retraining all of the developers, testers and release engineers, and not impacting their daily productivity, is a huge task. The existing system will have to be *really* broken.

Comment: the existing system often really *is* really broken, but it's only broken for devs, not for management: it sorta does the thing it's supposed to do, but it makes developers 10 time less productive

Comment: I've seen a major productivity jump from switching from svn to git, from the benefits of quick branching, so I have to assume that other DVCSes or VCSes are indeed hampering developer's workflows.

Comment: I'm not arguing against a DVCS. I use Git for some projects where it makes sense. I have to question the "10x less productive" claim, though. Be honest about how much of your day is spent writing code vs. actually working with your VCS. If you spent 90% less time in "VCS mode," but total time is 30 minutes, most management isn't going to take you seriously. I'm not saying it's right, I'm just being realistic. Companies will want proof that a big change like this is worth the time and money, and just because SOME devs will be fine with a DVCS does not mean ALL devs will.

Comment: it's not about how many seconds you spend in it. it's about how it affects your "flow"; it's similar to the way vim affects productivity.

I'm not making the argument against svn in particular (I've not much experience with it), but against commercial tools like starteam

Answer (score 2):

Git is a version control system with an attitude of collaboration and sharing. There is practically no way you can enforce a specific pattern of access and sharing. If the people who're using git don't want to follow your rules, the tool is not going to help you much.

Although I personally think this kind of organizational behaviour is stupid, I'm sure somewhere someone thinks it's a good idea. Maybe you're concerned that your unruly employees work on the wrong projects, or you're desperate to keep changes out of the code.

Answer (score 1):

**"Apart from the fact that the choice has already been made"**

That part of the statement is actually too important to disregard, because it ties in with the learning curve of any particular tool.  Learning, for example, SVN takes a while, and the learning process costs money in the form of developer time.  Learning git, in my experience, takes more time, and is made more complex in the absence of simplified interfaces (gittortoise's ongoing development not withstanding).  Plus Git has so many tools that it's learning curve could actually be considered more of a learning slope.

The payoff after getting over the curve is great, but the initial requirement is a barrier to adoption.

Answer (score 1):

A significant practical barrier to enterprise adoption, apart from lack of central control and integration as mentioned by Eric, is "ease of use".

If you are used to Subversion, or similar tools such as PVCS, then Git (and DVCS in general) represents a significant learning hill to climb -- both at the conceptual level and the daily workflow. In my (somewhat jaded) experience many enterprise developers are often unwilling to invest the effort in learning a new tool or concepts; and I fear will scupper any attempt to introduce DVCS.

Please prove me wrong

Answer (score 1):

Here are some specific recommendations. (read the full blog [here](http://blog.collab.net/cloudforge/subversion-or-git-decisions-decisions/#.UDZx2KPcDaW)).

If you have compelling requirements for a single, certain, master copy of your work, use Subversion. You can do this with Git, so long as there are no slip-ups. But you can’t do anything else with Subversion (slip-ups or no), and “compelling requirements” like Sarbanes-Oxley are happier with guarantees than possibilities.

If you plan to maintain parallel, largely shared but permanently somewhat different lines of the same product, use Git. One common example: perhaps you have a large product that you customize for each customer. The customizations are permanent, and generally not shared among code lines, but most of the code is common to all. Git was designed for just this case (in Git terms, local customizations to the common core, and occasional feature or bug-fix contributions back up-tree).

Neither of those? Take your pick, you should be fine with either tool.

Answer (score -1):

Part of the difficulty is not due to the sytem but to the organisation of the workers.

SVN is easy to understand and use
but better if used for few dev working on a single branch (or head)

Git is a good idea but the implementation is very disgusting
and it takes A LOT of time and work to do something as simple as putting your damn code in !

we still wait for a DECENT DVCS ...